# How to run Data Analysis using Google Confidential Space

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I want to analyze some sensitive data for an external organization - they store this data in Google Sheets.

I am willing to try using Confidential Spaces as they allow:

- high security for the data owners, since the system is built with a "no trust" basis
- best collaboration possible, since the data is handled AND stored on their side. Even if I wanted to see it I couldn't.

Unfortunately, the documentation is almost non-existent, and the examples are, well, very rare too. There is only one, written in Go, to see what is the highest number of 2 ([here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/confidential-vm/docs/analyze-with-confidential-space)). Even for this, the code seems to have a lot of verbose.

I am wondering if anyone has some experience using this solution and could answer the following question:

- [Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/confidential-vm/docs/analyze-with-confidential-space#create_a_service_account_for_the_workload), we are setting up a service account to access the data, which is in the example stored in multiple buckets. Is there anything against querying the Google Sheets v4 API using this service account, via a standard library like [GSpread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.2/)? I know that in this case, the data obtained would not be encrypted, but the point is in the collaboration, I would not handle the data myself, I would just write the code and they run it, so they would still be happy.

I found nothing much on YouTube, nor on the internet, but I might have missed something.

Second question:
Would someone know an (easier) alternative to enable me to run data analysis in their GCP organization, running completely on their end?

Thank you very much